# How can I stop Apple mail from converting strings containing "@" into mailto:?

Tags: mail.app

How can I stop Apple mail from converting strings containing "@" into a mailto: link?

Answer (score 0):

Not solutions but possible workarounds:

- Avoid pressing space/enter after such a string. Before paste/writing the string press space and left arrow. This creates empty space after the string. Paste/write the string and use right arrow key to navigate one space to the right and no conversion would take place. If this string is not at the end of mail then just navigate away using arrow keys.
- There is keyboard shortcut command-shift-T which is for "Make Plain Text" so after the conversion it can be easily undone. However, this applies to the whole mail and makes it plain text.

Comment: One can also press Cmd Z after the conversion to undo it, but it’s a bit a pain as well.